# Number of lines in Parsed file by PMD

Tags: pmd

I am using PMD for the first time. So I am not very sure about all the usage of it.

My goal is to find the total number of lines in all the files which are parsed by PMD.
Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: Not via out-of-the-box PMD. You could create a PMD extension to do that. However, I recommend using a tool designed to count lines of code, such as the ones [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/104756/1005481) and in the linked posts.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Can you be more specific how to use PMD extension? Do you have any examples for the same?

Comment: That is described in the PMD docs [here](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/howtowritearule.html). You'll have to write code though.